# Mapbox GL JS/Android: Draw User's 3D Vector Layer of Buildings

Tags: mapbox, 3d, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Here:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/

It's possible to draw 3D buildings by taking advantage of extrusions, however the 3D vector layer source is the Mapbox's underlying extract of the OSM:

> **The 'building' layer in the mapbox-streets vector source** contains building-height. data from OpenStreetMap.

What I'm looking for is to add my custom vector layer (Geojson, WFS) which contains Polygons with Z values (3D)/feature property called height. Thus (in case of GL JS, same exists for Android) to extend this example:

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/

To support extrusions or whatever it takes to draw 3D buildings in Mapbox GL JS.

I tried 2 approaches:

1. Simply add to the draw polygon from GeoJson example features with Z values - this is not working. Probably because from graphical perspective there is no automatic conversion from 2D polygon on the surface to 3D Box (like this is why there is a term called extrusions).
2. So then I tried to add vector source layer to the extrusion example. It seems that the requirements are: (a) `'type': 'fill-extrusion'`, (b) Feature property `'height'`, (c) Add `paint` attribute with the `'fill-extrusion-X'` sub attributes. This is the complete code - and this also not works. Where is my mistake?

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Add a GeoJSON polygon</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <style>
            body { margin:0; padding:0; }
            #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='map'></div>
        <script>
            mapboxgl.accessToken = 'my_token';
            var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
                container: 'map',
                style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
                center: [10.858185165380299, 48.364322957423497],
                zoom: 18
            });
            map.on('load', function () {
                map.addLayer({
                    'id': 'maine',
                    'type': 'fill-extrusion',
                    'minzoom': 15,
                    'source': {
                        'type': 'geojson',
                        'data': {
                            'type': 'Feature',
                             'properties': {
                                'id': 1,
                                'height': 100
                            },
                            'geometry': {
                                'type': 'Polygon',
                                'coordinates': [[
                                    [ 10.857372608433057, 48.364322957423497], 
                                    [ 10.858185165380299, 48.364322957423497], 
                                    [ 10.858171844774606, 48.363982227426746], 
                                    [ 10.857409240098711, 48.363991077585354], 
                                    [ 10.857372608433057, 48.364322957423497]]]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'paint': {
                        'fill-extrusion-color': '#aaa',
                        'fill-extrusion-height': [
                            "interpolate",
                            ["linear"],
                            ["zoom"],
                            15, 0,
                            15.05,
                            ["get", "height"]
                        ],
                        'fill-extrusion-opacity': .6,
                        'fill-color': '#088',
                        'fill-opacity': 0.8
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the error console, it explains that

'fill-color': '#088',
  'fill-opacity': 0.8

aren't valid paint properties for fill-extrusion layers.

See the example at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/3d-buildings/ and documentation at https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#layers-fill-extrusion